# Garbage Result in my code

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Hey guys so I was working on this code that finds the same numbers and display them  and so far the result is just random numbers I need help.

```
int main(void){
int arr[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 8 ,8, 9, 10};
int i;
int j;
int same[10];
int ctr = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 10; j > 0;j--){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
            same[ctr++] = arr[i];//store the similar numbers
        }
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf("%d", same[i]);
}
getch();
return 0;}
```

Comment: For an array of 10 elements, what is the top index? What is the initial value of `j` in the loops?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 10; j > 0;j--){` --> `for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for(j = i+1; j < 10;j++){` or Change logic, `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){` --> `for(i = 0; i < ctr; i++){`

Answer (score 1):

You're contradicting yourself. For the same array, you're using two different indexing scheme!!

- In outer loop (*ascending index*), you're indexing from `0` to `9`
- In inner loop (*decending index*), you're indexing `10` from `1`.

The inner loop indexing is [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), thereby accessing out of bound memory, which is *invalid*. This  causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make it

```
for(j = 9; j >= 0;j--)
```

After that, you're attempting to print the values of *all* elements in the `same` array, whereas all (*or none*) the element values may not be assigned a value, actually. You left the automatic variable uninitialized, thereby containing indeterminate values. Since the variable has never its address taken, attempting to *use* the value will again cause UB.

That said, once a match is found, you can use `continue` to jump to the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Start your second loop (the `j` loop) at 9 and go to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on codechef compiler, it was giving a run time error. Because  in your ctr++ step , value of ctr exceeded the size of the array same[].

Moreover, in your code you are comparing one element with itself so every number will be printed in the list(since i==j may be a possible case)

It will be better if you include a condition `i!=j` with it or iterate `j from i+1 to 9` so that no self comparisons are done. The following is a working snippet of the same code(your for loop) :-

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(j = 10; j > 0;j--){
        if(arr[i] == arr[j] && i!=j){
            same[ctr] = arr[i];//store the similar numbers
            ctr++;
            cout<<ctr<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```